# How can i restart the node server in electron application?

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules, electron-builder, firmware

I have an electron application that runs fine, but the node server get crash due to some errors so I want to restart the node in electron without relaunching the electron application.

Is there any way that I can run restart the node server?

Answer (score 0):

The "node server" is called the [main process](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model#the-main-process), and in a sense it is the "electron application".

But what you could do is run some or all of your node code in a [utility process](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model#the-utility-process).  Your main process could then listen for the *exit* event of that utility process, and restart it if that ever happened.

The other job of your main process is then likely to be as a go-between, passing messages between that utility process and the front-end renderer process.

If you know it is just one function that is unstable then it may be simpler to run just that in a dedicated utility process.